# How to convert a class's recursive function to be a redux action?

Tags: javascript, redux

A recursive function shown bellow locates in a class. And, no state modification happens in the code section.

```
//delete target node and its subtree
function deleteSubTree(cur,nodearray){
    if(the node is not a leave) {
         //go to leaves
         deleteSubTree(cur.child,nodearray);
    }
    else{
        delete cur;
        if(cur.parent has a child) deleteSubTree(cur.parent,nodearray)
        else return;
    }
}
```

But because now I need to refactor my code to fit the redux framework, I need to turn this into a action.
I think it should be converted to be

```
export function deleteSubTreeAction(node) {
    return (diespatch)=>{
         ....
        dispatch(deleteSubTreeAction(node.rChild));
         ...
    };
}
```

However, this looks quite weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the end condition of the recursion? How should the redux state change when it's done? My wild guess is that you should pass dispatch to the recursive calls, but only call it if the end condition becomes true.

Comment: The setState happens only after the whole deleteSubTree finishes. the output of deleteSubTree is used to be setState-ed.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two actions:

1. `DELETE_SUBTREE_START`
2. `DELETE_SUBTREE_END`

Dispatch them like this:

```
// Helper function / side effect
function deleteSubTree(cur, nodearray, done){
    if(the node is not a leave) {
         //go to leaves
         deleteSubTree(cur.child, nodearray, done);
    }
    else {
        delete cur;
        if (cur.parent has a child) {
            deleteSubTree(cur.parent, nodearray, done)
        } else {
            return done();
        }
    }
}

// Action creator
export function deleteSubTreeAction(node) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        ...
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_SUBTREE_START' });
        deleteSubTree(
            node.rChild,
            ?, // not sure if you need the second argument here?
            () => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_SUBTREE_END' })
        );
        ...
    };
}
```

This way the recursive function can signal when it's `done()` and can take as long as it needs. For performance, consider limiting the maximum tree depth though, which could dispatch something like `DELETE_SUBTREE_ABORT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, timotgl. I need to consider more and plan carefully before doing this.